# Load CSS per custom role

Tags: css, wordpress, buddypress

I want to hide activity posting in buddypress for all users except admin. I want only admin to post update. Is that possible?

heres the css

```
.activity form#whats-new-form {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is possible, and @Aliqua's solution should work. Just know that using CSS for this isn't fully secure, and it's generally considered a better practice to try and find the form/capability and unhook it with PHP

Comment: Agreed, or `enqueue_script()` but you would need to add `!important` at the end and probably want more css to warrant it..

Comment: anyone have suggestion using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)

```
add_action('wp_head', 'hide_activity');
function hide_activity() {
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ){
        echo '<style>
            .activity form#whats-new-form {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>';
    }
}
```

Goes in your `functions.php` file or plugin file.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/